# delete schedule task using shell_exec php

Tags: php

I have code like this for delete schedule task using command line

```
SchTasks /Delete /TN ReminderKontrak
```

and the command prompt show the warning like this 
[image]

And now I want implementation that code to php, so be like this

```
shell_exec('SchTasks /Delete /TN ReminderKontrak');
```

but the result is not delete the task, maybe it because the warning like in command prompt? maybe that possible to make automatically send `Y` when warning is show?

Comment: IF? how I can implement that?

Comment: I would probably not delete / add tasks from php. Instead I would keep a config file or something similar to keep track of which tasks need to be executed and check for that at the start of each scheduled script.

Comment: @PaulCrovella oh yeah it's work.. If u want answer it, I will accept that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the [`/F`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357(v=vs.85).aspx#deleting_a_task) flag to  forcefully delete the task and suppress warnings, e.g.:

```
shell_exec('SchTask‌​s /Delete /TN ReminderKontrak /F');
```